# How to get rid of "read-only" filesystem?

Tags: permissions

To save some disk space, I recently deleted all the epiphany software that had been
installed in my /snap directory.   However, I still had numerous epiphany files, which were marked "read only".  I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

For example, the installed files include ones named "actions", "apps", "LC_MESSAGES",
etc., and contain files named "epiphany-browser.svg", "epiphany-bookmarks.svg", etc.

I have tried many things, but I can not remove these files except by deleting the
containing applications and reinstalling them.   Some of these apps include vital dates
or times which would be lost if deleted.

How do I get rid of the "read only" files causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`/var/lib/snapd/snap` (or `/snap`) is not mounted as a normal filesystem, but as a [loop device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device), you need to remove the software using the snap cli and not manually.